# deploy postgresql to kubenetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

## Step to reproduce the issue

1. `helm pull bitnami/postgresql`
2. `tar -xf postgresql-8.4.3.tgz && cd postgresql`
3. Update values-production.yaml with storageClass: "local-path", postgresqlPassword: root, postgresqlDatabase: test
4. `helm upgrade --install -f values-production.yaml postgresql .`
5. `kubectl get all`

## The results I received:

- postgresql-master is running
- postgresql-slave is not running

## The results i expected:

- postgresql-master is running
- postgresql-slave is running

Comment: Why are you using such a completely outdated and unmaintained Postgres version?

Answer (score 0):

please try to install postgresql cluster using oparator.
you can use 
1. https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md#deployment-options
2. https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator

Both of them are popular postgresql operator.
i would like to suggest you crunchydata PGO.you can easily install it from [this](https://www.crunchydata.com/developers/download-postgres/containers/postgres-operator)

Answer (score -1):

```
helm upgrade --install --debug -f values-production.yaml postgresql .
```

could you please try a debug and --dry-run as well? also please refer this ReadMe.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/postgresql/README.md